# GitHub Jira Cloud Commit History

Tags: github, jira

I have a private GitHub repo that has been rebased a few times and a Jira ticket that is tracking.  GitHub and Jira are linked so the commits are tagged to the Jira ticket.

The issue is that previous rebased commits still show on the Jira ticket.  The GitHub history is correct?  I’m assuming these are cached somewhere In Jira rather than looking through the reflog?  I’ve tried a full sync for the Jura’s GitHub App but the rebased commits still show.  Is there a way to remove the links?